# Django with MySQL: Invalid utf8 character string: '800363' how to fix it?

Tags: mysql, python, django, python-3.x

When I store data to MySQL from Django, I get an error:

```
Django Version: 1.7.7
Exception Type: Warning
Exception Value:    
Invalid utf8 character string: '800363'
Exception Location: /home/virtualenv/examenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in _warning_check, line 127
Python Executable:  /home/virtualenv/examenv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.4.4
```

Model

```
class Test(models.Model):
    """
    The model of the test
    """

    # The name of the test
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    # The description of test
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    # The test
    test = models.BinaryField(blank=True)
    # The author of the test
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    # The category of the test
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    # date and time of create test
    date_and_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    # How many users complete this test.
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # Public or not public test
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have created the data base in utf-8 format
How to fix this error?

Comment: Hi Alexey, i have the same problem, did you solve it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the stack trace or the line that produces the error this is a blind guess. However, I do see a BinaryField in your model. I suppose you are using Python MySql Connector.

I solved this same bug by encoding the binary data as hex bytestring. I actually wouldn't expect this to solve anything, binary is binary, but this is how I got it working:

```
import binascii
bin_data = some_function()  
repr(bin_data)
>>> b"R\x89\x9e\x86\xc6" # or something like that
test = Test()
# ...
hex_bin_data = binascii.hexlify(bin_data)
test.test = hex_bin_data
test.save()
```

The `hex_bin_data` output is `bytes` too. And this is something that bugs me. What makes Python differentiate between `bin_data` and `hex_bin_data`? There supposed to be the same bytes no?